# angular-uiroute error as $cookieStore.get is undefind

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, session-cookies

here im trying to fetch my Stored cookie value in $roortScope why im getting Error as .get of undefind  `$cookieStore.get('mycookie');`

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngCookies']).controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $cookies, $state) {
 .run(function ($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options, $scope,$cookieStore) {
            var Getcookies = $cookieStore.get('mycookie');

            if (toState.module == "Private" && !Getcookies.lenth=='undefind') 
  {
            }
```

Comment: did you add var app = angular.module('test', ['ngCookies']); to the module

Comment: yes i added ngCookies

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is in your controller you have $cookies

```
.controller('HomeCtrl', function ($scope, $cookies, $state)
```

but in your function you are using $cookieStore thats why your $cookieStore is undefined

```
function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options, $scope,$cookieStore)
```

if you want to use $cookieStore you should change the $cookies in your controller with $cookieStore but keep in mind that $cookieStore is deprecated since version 1.4, you should use $cookies instead if you are using a newer version than 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

The `$cookies` service needs to be injected as a parameter in the `.run` construction function:

```
̶.̶r̶u̶n̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶$̶r̶o̶o̶t̶S̶c̶o̶p̶e̶)̶ ̶{̶
.run(function ($rootScope, $cookies) {

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, options, $scope,$cookieStore) {
        var Getcookies = $cookies.get('mycookie');

        //...

    });
})
```